# Complex search Laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Good night. I am trying to build a search engine but i am coming up blank with how to build the search. I have about 8 input fields for the user to enter all of which can be null/blank. See what i was trying to do below:

I need help in building the query so it can actually work. When i run this query it brings up the data with data_name1. But if i put a title in from a different row in the database it doesn't show anything for that one. So the query only shows 1 result event when the title is exact for multiple different rows

```
$data = DB::table('inventory')
    ->where('data_name1', 'like', $request->data_name1.'%')
    ->orWhere('data_name2', 'like', $request->data_name2.'%')
    ->orWhere('title', 'like', $request->title.'%')
    ->orWhere('caption', '=', $request->caption)
    ->whereIn('part', [$request->front, $request->back, $request->side, $request->center])
    ->orWhere('ppd', '=', $request->ppd)
    ->orWhere('user', '=', $request->user)
    ->whereBetween('year', [$request->startyear, $request->endyear])
    ->get();
```

Update. But with the code below it only checks one row. I want it to bring back data from different rows if the criteria match

```
$data = $data->newQuery();
    if($request-> data_name1) {
        $data->where('data_name1', 'LIKE', $request-> data_name1.'%');
    }
    if($request-> data_name2) {
        $data->where('data_name2', 'LIKE', $request-> data_name2.'%');
    }
    if($request->title) {
        $data->where('title', 'LIKE', $request->title.'%');
    }
    if($request-> caption) {
        $data->where('caption', 'LIKE', $request-> caption.'%');
    }
    if($request-> part) {
        $data->where('part', $request-> part);
    }
    if($request->ppd) {
        $data->where('ppd', $request->ppd);
    }
    if($request-> user) {
        $data->where('user', $request-> user);
    }
    if($request->startyear) {
        $data->whereBetween('year', [$request->startyear, $request->endyear]);
    }
```

Comment: so what's the problem here??what can we do for you??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I just updated the post. Need help with building the query

Comment: is there any compulsory field for search..? like data_name1 or year or part? and give your model name

Comment: @karen Yeh data_name1 is compulsory

Comment: I came up with something else See update @karen

Comment: show us how your request looks like, you can do a `dd($request->all())`

Comment: Add this package https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter. Easily manage complex search & filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use when and a lot of orWhere... methods. Does this work for you?

```php
$data = DB::table('inventory')
->when($request->has('data_name1'), function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->orWhere('data_name1', 'LIKE', $request->data_name1.'%');
})
->when($request->has('data_name2'), function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->orWhere('data_name2', 'LIKE', $request->data_name2.'%');
})
->when($request->has('title'), function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', $request->title.'%');
})
->when($request->has('caption'), function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->orWhere('caption', 'LIKE', $request->caption.'%');
})
->when($request->has('part'), function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->orWhere('part', $request->part);
})
// Alternatively
// ->when($request->has(['front', 'back', 'side', 'center']), function ($query) use ($request) {
//     $query->orWhereIn('part', [$request->front, $request->back, $request->side, $request->center]);
// })
->when($request->has('ppd'), function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->orWhere('ppd', $request->ppd);
})
->when($request->has('user'), function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->orWhere('user', $request->user);
})
->when($request->has(['startyear', 'endyear']), function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->orWhereBetween('year', [$request->startyear, $request->endyear]);
})
->get();
```